# Simple jQuery in CakePHP example not working

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Im trying to add jQuery to one of my projects, but can't get it working.

/views/layouts/default.ctp

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.6.4.js');
echo $this->Html->script('test.js');
```

/view/test/view.ctp

```
<?php echo $html->link('click msg', '#', array('onclick'=>'return false;', 'id'=>'msg-name', 'class'=>'msg-link')); ?>
```

/views/layouts/js/test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.msg-link').click( function () 
    {
        alert("Thanks for clicking.");
    });
});
```

which should then popup an alert when i click the button / link, but its doesn't do anything :(

Also I'm the debug console of chrome i see this error:

```
/js/jquery-1.6.4.js:-1 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
/js/test.js:-1 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
jquery-1.6.4.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
test.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Im not really sure what they mean and can't see how stock query can have errors in it.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to copy js files to /webroot/js/.

Then you have to set in your ctp file this:

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.6.4');
echo $this->Html->script('test');
```

Comment: Hi Chalist, Thanks :) I have just found this out... unless i missed it, its not very well documented that is has to be put in /webroot/js/ rather than where i put it in /views/layouts/js/

Answer (score 5):

Drop the .js extension.

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.6.4');
echo $this->Html->script('test');
```

> This method of javascript file inclusion assumes that the javascript file specified resides inside the /app/webroot/js directory.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html?highlight=html#HtmlHelper::script

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, have tried that and both don't make a difference, in the html it links correctly /js/jquery-1.6.4.js both when i have the .js and without :(